# System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll in c# program

Tags: c#, .net, file, dll

I' like to use the dll [System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) in my project

[image: file]

the .net framework version is 4.5 and the os is 64. The problem is that the dll is not found.
[image: config]
What is the solution?

Comment: Do you have full .NET 4.5 installed?  It's not Client Profile?  Is the screenshot you provided showing that you can ask for the DLL but then it cannot be found?

Comment: You are getting assembly name and namespaces mixed up. Using should be the Namespace which is just System.IO.Compression

Comment: @DonBoitnott I believe they got rid of the Client Profile stuff with 4.5.

Comment: @JoeEnos I just found that in a different search; you are correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The namespace is not the same as the dll name (assembly name). [from the MSDN page you linked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx)

> **Namespace**:  System.IO.Compression
>   **Assembly**:  System.IO.Compression.FileSystem (in System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll)

So the namespace you need to include is `System.IO.Compression` not `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`. Take off the `FileSystem` part from your `using` statement and it will solve your problem.

---

If people are down-voting me because the OP said "The problem is that the dll is not found." I think the OP is not using the correct word choice, if the problem really was that the DLL could not be found there would be a exclamation point by the assembly name which the original screenshot does not have

See the original image below

[image: Original Image]
(click for larger view)

Compare that to my screenshot I created that would show up if the DLL really was not found, note the exclamation point I have that the original screenshot does not.

[image]

Comment: @Lamloumi Ok, what about it. The Namespace is still `System.IO.Compression`, the problem [your screenshot shows](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0auH7.jpg) is that you have a red underline under `FileSystem`, that is because that part is not part of the namespace name. The full path of the function you linked would be `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(String, String)` not `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(String, String)`

Comment: sorry i misunderstood you :)

Answer (score 4):

in the System.IO.Compression there's no such class as FileSystem check it out the link on the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a.aspx)

the classes available are:

> - DeflateStream Provides methods and properties for compressing and decompressing streams by using the Deflate algorithm.
> - GZipStream Provides methods and properties used to compress and decompress streams.
> - ZipArchive Represents a package of compressed files in the zip archive format.
> - ZipArchiveEntry    Represents a compressed file within a zip archive.
> - ZipFile    Provides static methods for creating, extracting, and opening zip archives.
> - ZipFileExtensions

if your goal is to use compression of file or stream use the [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) class.

However remove the FileSystem from the using statement:

```
using System.IO.Compression;
```

Anyway as Joe Enos has pointed out classes from the Compression namespace have been taken out the Client Profile from the framework 4.5

Below the Version Information from the msdn about the GZipStream:

> .NET Framework
>       Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0
>
> .NET Framework Client Profile
>      Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1

Comment: OP didn't say it was a namespace issue...it cannot find the DLL.  The DLL name given is valid.

Comment: @DonBoitnott the solution is to remove FileSystem from the using the dll is referenced from the solution

Comment: @DonBoitnott I'd disagree, this answer is correct.  Look at the screenshot: the problem isn't missing dll the problem is the using statement fails

Comment: @JohnField I see that now.  I was more focused on the assembly list.  My apologies.  Downvote rescinded.

Comment: @DonBoitnott no problem at all :)

Answer (score 2):

A new nuget package is coming out. Check this out :)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile

Answer (score -3):

Adding reference to System.IO.Compression.dll solved this issue for me.